# Select .state on page reload angularjs(using angular-ui-router)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am developing a ASP.NET MVC 5 application. I am loading a partial view through angular `'ui.router'` on a `div` in a parent page. Routing is working great until I refresh the page - than a partial view is loading on a whole page but I want it to still load as a partial.

This is my code. A parent view, FirstPage.cshtml:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <base href="/">
    <title>First Page</title>
    <script src="/Scripts/Angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/Angular/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>First Page</h1>
    <ul id="myMenu">
        <li ui-sref="customer">Customer</li>
    </ul>
    <div ui-view="containerOne"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my app.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.router']);

var proposalConfig = function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {

$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!').html5Mode(true);

$stateProvider
    .state('customer', {
        url: 'Proposal/Customers',
        views: {
            "containerOne": {
                templateUrl: '/Proposal/Customers'
            }
        }
    });
}

proposalConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider'];

myApp.config(proposalConfig);
```

My RouteConfig.cs:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ProposalCustomers",
    url: "Proposal/Customers",
    defaults: new { controller = "Proposal", action = "Customers" });

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

My ProposalController.cs:

```
public ActionResult Customers()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult FirstPage()
{
    return View();
}
```

My Views/Proposal/Customers.cshtml:

```
<h2>Customer list</h2>
```

I hope my problem is clear.

EDIT:

I changed my RouteConfig.cs following the solution from this article:

> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/806500/Getting-started-with-AngularJS-and-ASP-NET-MVC-P

to have a default route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{*url}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Proposal", action = "FirstPage" }
```

When I refresh a page that has a route exactly like my `controller/action`, it still loads that specific route on a whole page instead as a partial. If I change a .state `url` to something else page refresh is working. But still if I put manually a `controller/action` path in the URL, it shows a view on a whole page instead as a partial.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change you `ng-view` to `ui-view` as you are using angular `$stateProvider` not angular `$routeProvider`

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <h1>First Page</h1>
    <ul id="myMenu">
        <li ui-sref="customer">Customer</li>
    </ul>
    <div ui-view=""></div>
</body>
```

You stateProvider should be change which is currently using single view and you declared it as like you are using nested-views

**Config**

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.router']);

var proposalConfig = function($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!').html5Mode(true);

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/Proposal/Customers'); //default redirection if no route matched

    $stateProvider.state('customer', {
        url: '/Proposal/Customers',
        templateUrl: '/Proposal/Customers',
        controller: 'someController' //if you want
    });

}

proposalConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider'];

myApp.config(proposalConfig);
```

Hope this could help you, Thanks.

Comment: I mistyped here...in my solution i have ui-view and it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what I'm guessing is happening is you mapped a route in your MVC application to serve the same route as your angular application, in this instance, you mapped 'Proposal/Customers' in your MVC router and in your Angular-UI-Router.

So what is happening is that if you're already in your Angular application, the Angular router has control and as you navigate around, it is loading the template as a child template and putting the HTML into the correct location.  When you refresh, you're sending that route to the MVC router, though, and it's serving the HTML as the page.

*EDIT*

Forgot to mention, this is happening because you've got html5 routing turned on.

Comment: Yes I know whats the problem, but I don't know the way to solve it. :) Do you know? :)

Comment: The only solution I know of is to either force a mapping to your AngularJS starting point in your MVC routes (i.e. change your MVC routing) or not use HTML5 routing in your AngularJS App.  If you use a # symbol, MVC automatically ignores it.  If there is a different way around it, I don't know it at the moment.  Maybe somebody with some intricate knowledge of MVC route mapping can recommend a viable solution.